# i want to notify the user when phone is charging,like DUbattery saver app notifies by screen overlay when phone is charging

Tags: android, screen, overlay, android-notifications, android-broadcastreceiver

i want to notify the user when phone is charging,like DUbattery saver app notifies by screen overlay when phone is charging

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    try {

        IntentFilter ifilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED);
        Intent batteryStatus = context.registerReceiver(null, ifilter);

        int status = batteryStatus.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_STATUS, -1);
        boolean isCharging = status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_CHARGING ||
                status == BatteryManager.BATTERY_STATUS_FULL;

        if (isCharging == true) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "PLEASE UNPLUG", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
```

i have implemented this code in broadcastreceiver,how can i notify the user ,
or by opening the the app when phone is charging

Comment: or i want to open a app automatically when phone is connected to power

Answer (score 0):

Use an intent to launch your app when you get the callback in your broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 0):

If your broadcast receiver is getting called properly than you can open your activity or application using startactivity() method.

Something like this :

```
startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), youractivityname.class).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open the activity, all you need to do is generate a `intent` for your activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Context, YourActivityClass.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

If otherwise you want to notify the user with some notification, you can 
If you want further info about intents and how start your activity, you should create a notification:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
    new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
    .setContentTitle("My notification")
    .setContentText("Hello World!");
// Sets an ID for the notification
int mNotificationId = 001;
// Gets an instance of the NotificationManager service
NotificationManager mNotifyMgr = 
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// Builds the notification and issues it.
mNotifyMgr.notify(mNotificationId, mBuilder.build());
```

Take a look to Android documentation about [intents](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) or about notification[2].

Comment: thanks spaniard...i want to notify by screen overlay same as like DUbattery app does by notifying a screen layer when phone is connected to  power

Comment: the notification screen will display by overlaying above the current activity we do....

Comment: With overlay the current activity, you mean your activity or any activity the user is running?

Comment: myactivity which i implemented...the activity which i want to overlay the current activity of the user when the phone is charging

Comment: I am not sure how to achieve to overlay one activity with another one. I suggest you to try use  a lowest alpha in the parent layout and modify that alpha in the parts you want to be visible. But I am not sure this could work.

Answer (score 0):

To check the state of the battery(charging or not)..use this code..

```
public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
    Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
    int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
}
```

Then if this function returns true..show the notification by this code..

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentTitle("Charging State")
    .setContentText("Your phone is charging");
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
```

Comment: bro actually the  code  you said will listen  the charge state and immediately nofies  whenever the power is connected

Comment: i want  the app to listen  the charging  state  and notify only  the phone is connected to power.

Comment: this should be implemented in activity or in broadcastreceiver

Answer (score 0):

First prepare broadcast receiver to listen for changes to ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED, and in turn flag the screen to stay on.
Then in onReceive of Broadcast Receiver-

> public void onReceive {
>       public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
>           Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
>           int plugged = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
>           return plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || plugged == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
>       } }

After that just simply notify the user with notification

> NotificationCompat.Builder builder =
>       new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
>       .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
>       .setContentTitle("Phone Status")
>       .setContentText("Charging");
>
> int notificationId = 12345;
>
> NotificationManager notificationManager = 
>           (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
>
> notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());

Comment: this whole code is already in a onReceive method of broadcastreceiver, but if you handle notification separately so fire any intent service from onReceive which do this notification job in background.